# Best Way to Assert That Each String in a Collection Contains a Substring?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

What is the best way to assert that each element in a collection of strings contains a particular substring?

Something like

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("xyfoobar", "foobarxy", "xyfoobarxy");

assertThat(list, eachElementContains("foobar")); // pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to use hamcrest library. Please try :

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.everyItem;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("xyfoobar", "foobarxy", "xyfoobarxy");
        assertThat(list, (everyItem(containsString("foobar"))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Something simple like:

```
list.forEach(string -> {
    assertTrue(string.contains("foobar"));
});
```

This doesn't use Hamcrest matchers but has the same semantics.

Comment: The braces of your lambda are redundant here btw.

Comment: Yes, i go through phases of wanting all lambdas to fit on a single line, and other phases of wanting everything spread out, currently in a spread out phase :p

Comment: This will make an assert for every element from list. I think he want one assert over all.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is preferrable? I am not familiar with the specifics of the assert variants, so am unaware if this leads to performance impacts. If so, you could also use `assertTrue(list.stream().allMatch(s -> s.contains("foobar")));`

Comment: Yes, @KunLun. If I have 100 elements in a list It would be nice when all elements are checked instead of failing at the first not-match. Furthermore, in the error output, it's hard to see which of the 100 elements made the assertion fail. It does its job, tho.

Answer (score 2):

If you use AssertJ:

`import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;`

you could do the following:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("xyfoobar", "foobarxy", "xyfoobarxy");
list.forEach(entry->assertThat(entry).describedAs("should contains 'foobar'").contains("foobar"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do the trick

```
         List<String> result = list.stream()                // convert list to stream
             .filter(str ->str.indexOf("foobar")!=-1)     // collects all "foobar" substring
             .collect(Collectors.toList());              // collect the output and convert streams to a List

 assertThat(list.equals(result)).isTrue();
```

Comment: why not? just look if the two lists are in the same size

Comment: or equals as in the example